# Create a volume in docker from windows host

Tags: docker

I have the following folder on my windows host
C:\Tmp\TmpVolume
"TmpVolume" has a number of files.

This is where I will be putting my sourcecode for development purposes on the host machine.

Now I want to run the container and mount this folder onto the container.  This is the command I execute

```
docker run -p 49160:3000  -v C:/Tmp/TmpVolume/:/usr/src/app/TmpVolume -d containerName
```

My problem is that when I move into the directory /usr/src/app in the container there is a TmpVolume folder but this empty, there is nothing inside it.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked that the Docker manager (whichever you are using) has permissions to share the C:/Tmp folder?

Comment: what do you mean by the Docker manager, sorry I am new to Docker and still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Get rid of the trailing slash on `C:/Tmp/TmpVolume/` > `C:/Tmp/TmpVolume`.

Comment: Which Windows app, Docker Toolbox, Docker for Windows (beta), etc.

Comment: Actually I had not given permission to the drive. Now when I give permission I can see the contents. Now my problem is that any file I modify from the host os (windows) does not get reflected on the container when I view the contents.  I use the following command to view the contents cat <filename>.  However when I add a new file (with contents) to the folder from the host os I can see the file, but in this new file also when I try cat <newfilename> it shows nothing.